# How can I make sure that my Autonomous Database automatic backups are scheduled when the instance is stopped?

Tags: oracle, oracle-autonomous-db

The automatic backups are scheduled to run at night but I want to keep my ADB instance stopped at nights. What happens if the database is unavailable/stopped when the system tries to take an automatic backup?  Does it fail or is it rescheduled?

Answer (score 0):

Stopping your database has no effect on ADB taking automatic backups; it can still backup the database when it is in the stopped state.